# Altium: the shortcut key +/- don't move me to the next layers

Tags: altium, routing, via, layers

I have created multiple layers from the stack layer manager. Also created vias from layer 1 to 2, and 1 to 3. When I clicked okay, the layer image didn't get updated, meaning it didnt add the vias I created (not sure if this is normal).

My guess is that because the vias weren't created, altium can't move me to the next layers. But then again, I have the default vias between layer 1 and last layer.

[image]

Which brings us back to the main question, why is my shortcut keys not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you are using a laptop, it happened to me, it only works with the numerical pad. There are some workarounds, have a look at this thread:
[Altium keyboard shortcuts issues](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/altium/altium-keyboard-shortcut-issues-18647/)

Comment: +1 Usually there is a phantom numeric keyboard on laptops- but it appears this doesn't work with Altium. I guess one solution is to use an external keyboard!